# I want to console.log() only my data present in my MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, console.log

I am entering data in my database in mongodb and want to console.log() the data entered but whenever I try to do it, my data do come to console but with various other properties, which I do not need.
I just want to bring the data entered on my console !

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/playground")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("database connected");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Could not connect", err);
  });

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  author: String,
  tags: [String],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  isPublished: Boolean
});

// To Create a class of Course, we need to use the model method
const Course = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);

async function createCourse() {
  //Lets create a object to the Course class
  // Async Routine
  const course = new Course({
    name: "React Course",
    author: "Mosh",
    tags: ["FrontEnd", "React"],  
    isPublished: true
  });

  // Log Tree : Schema -> Model -> Class -> Object !....

  const result = await course.save();
  console.log(result);
}



async function getCourse() {
  const course = await Course.find();

//Bringing the data from the data base.  

  console.log(course);
}

getCourse();
```

What I want to be displayed on my console is (Actual Data in my mongo data base)

```
[ {"_id":{"$oid":"5e847c6e6ed0fa2c785647e4"},
"tags":["Backend","Node"],
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1585740910542"}},
"name":"Node Course",
"author":"Mosh","isPublished":true,
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}   
} , 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5e84868970369f3a30e25270"},
"tags":["FrontEnd","React"],
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1585743497438"}},
"name":"React Course",
"author":"Mosh",
"isPublished":true,"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"} } ]
```

BUT What I get is my data BUT with this extra information :-

```
[
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: {},
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5e847c6e6ed0fa2c785647e4,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      tags: [Array],
      date: 2020-04-01T11:35:10.542Z,
      _id: 5e847c6e6ed0fa2c785647e4,
      name: 'Node Course',
      author: 'Mosh',
      isPublished: true,
      __v: 0
    },
    '$init': true
  },
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: {},
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5e84868970369f3a30e25270,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      tags: [Array],
      _id: 5e84868970369f3a30e25270,
      name: 'React Course',
      isPublished: true,
      __v: 0
    },
    '$init': true
  }
]
```

I dont want this extra information along with my data, when I console.log my Class !

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. I was running mongoose 5.0.1, just updated the mongoose package and It stopped displaying other properties  !

Comment: Hey, I just want to ask, I know this is an old question, but what happens if you loop through all the values in the schema and console.log each one of the values? My console.log works fine, but when I loop through each of the items and display them, there is a lot of extra information. Does that occur in your example too? My mongoose is already up to date.